# Embed plotly:dash figure inside django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

Looking forward to finding out some possible way to use plotly dash table or other figures in existing Django app template.

I have been digging into this problem for the last 36 hours. As i understand dash ends up serving in its own server .  Theres barely much documentation and easy to understand examples that supporst my needs. All i could find is the following

1. eads method however this method helps run plotly:dash inside Django with completely separate url. Its not like i have an existing template and i can add the dash figure inside there .
2. django-plotly-dash is a library I was looking into i went through the entire documentation and tried ,yself however i always end up getting errors like 'No reverse match at' or like 'not a valid namspace ' and so on.

Just one example showing how i can integrate dash figures inside Django template.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/tree/master/demo/demo ? That's the `django-plotly-dash` you mentioned.

Comment: yes i have checked this demo. that's the one giving me the error.

Comment: I'd advise to put the code and stack trace, with exact errors. Otherwise it's going to be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting no reverse match and not valid namespace errors, you're probably missing a url definition.

It's not possible to solve your precise problem without a bit more information, but something that went wrong for me which was quite similar to what you've described was that I failed to include the `django_plotly_dash` urls. If you miss these, you'll get a failed reverse/namespace for an app called `the_django_plotly_dash`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("django_plotly_dash/", include("django_plotly_dash.urls")),
    ...
]
```